# adding class to excerpt

Tags: theme-development, excerpt

I want to add different classes to some excerpts.when wrap the excerpt with

it doesn't work.how can I add my class to excerpt?

```
<?php
<p class="myclass"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
```

output:

```
<p class="myclass"></p><p>excerpt text</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_excerpt()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/) bascially echo(es) the `get_the_excerpt()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/) output, which in turns wraps the `$post->post_excerpt` value in html `<p>` tags.

So you can either strip the html markup,

```
<p class="myclass"><?= wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ) ?></p>
```

or, if you have access to the `$post` object simply,

```
<p class="myclass"><?= $post->post_excerpt ?></p>
```